# Need help getting google analytics to authenticate - "cannot import name 'util' from 'oauth2client'

Tags: api, libraries, oauth2client

I'm trying to get google analytics API to authenticate, and whilst I can find loads of tutorials online they all involve the following code:

```
#Load Libraries
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

But when I try to import those libraries I get:
ImportError: cannot import name 'util' from 'oauth2client'

I know that oauth2client is deprecated but I don't understand why this doesn't work? And I can't find an alternative either.

Any advice would be very gratefully received - as I'm currently falling at the first hurdle!